# Factor graphs: HMM

Tags: probability, markov-chains, machine-learning

A friend of mine and me are struggling for a while now on how to start with [this example](http://www.igi.tugraz.at/lehre/MLA/WS13/MLA_Exercises_2013/node6.html) that we have to work out.

---

There is a 10x10 map which an agent is randomly placed on. The single tiles of that map are randomly colored. There are 10 colors encoded by the numbers 1 to 10.

All that is given is a vector of observed colors $ \bf{x} = \{ 3,1,..,8 \} $ that the agent reported to us after making 20 steps. He either stays at his current location with a probability of 25% or moves up, down, left or right, where each of these four actions is chosen with a probability of 18.75%.

We are now supposed to implement the sum-product algorithm to find the most likely trajectories and the probabilities of the agent positions on each time step as inferred by the sum-product algorithm.

---

Unfortunately we don't have a clue how to begin with this. We know how the sum-product algorithm works but we are stuck here on the very beginning.

Comment: So it sounds like you don't know for sure where the agent starts?  You just know where the agent was after the first turn?

Comment: No, it is not given where the agent starts. Like I said, only the 10x10 map included the tile colors are given and the vector of observed colors plus the transition probabilities.